# How to add UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I am trying yo add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to one of UITextField on page but It does not call the selector method when Long Press the UiTextField.
 I added it to UItextField But it does not call the Selector method when I Long press the TextField but Showing the Magnifier on Field.

```
[self.tfCustomerStreet addGestureRecognizer:LongPressgesture];
```

But it works fine and call the selector Method if I add it to the View.

```
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:LongPressgesture];
```

Initialization code in ViewDidLoad

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *LongPressgesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LongPressgesture:)];
    [LongPressgesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];
```

.

```
// Long press gesture reconizer
- (void)LongPressgesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Long press Ended .................");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Long press detected .....................");
    }        
}
```

Please tell me How do I make it work with UITextField.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you remove the `[LongPressgesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];` it will work .. since the tab gesture will be called to start edit the textField ... or just implement this gesture delegate function

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

returning YES to this method is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition.

Enjoy :)

Comment: thanks Malek .. its start working on removal of [LongPressgesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0]; but does not work if add your mentioned code.   but problem solved .. thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome .. but for the second sloution did you add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in .h ?

Comment: also you need to set `LongPressgesture.delegate = self;`