# how can I make delete the textfield when i long pressed it.?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

Im having this problem for weeks already. because my app needs a function that will create a UITextfield, undo, and delete the UITexfield. my code create textfield anywhere on the view when you tap it. and it also can undo the last textfield that been created when pressed button undo, it can be move, scale, rotate also, but after i created another new textfield, the old one was been attached to the view. that is why when i long pressed the old textfield, it can be deleted only the new one that was been created can be delete. what will i do how to make that old textfield deleted?here my code.

```
ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{

    NSMutableArray *textfieldform;//array for textfield
    UITextField *textField1;//a textfield
    CGPoint prevPanPoint;// float for moving the textfield anywhere
    float prevPinchScale;// float for pinching the textfield
    float prevRotation;// float for rotating the textfield
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *textfieldform;//array for creating multiple textfield


-(IBAction) undo;
- (IBAction)handleTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
-(IBAction)panGestureAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan;
- (IBAction)scaleImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (IBAction)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
@end

ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize textfieldform;
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //textfieldform = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    textfieldform = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];//array of the textfield
}
//connected to the self.view
-(IBAction) longPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
    [textfieldform removeObject:textField1];
    [textField1 removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"baaaaaaam!");
}
//make the textfield move to any direction in the self.view
-(IBAction)panGestureAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
    CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:self.view];
    textField1.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(textField1.transform, translation.x, translation.y);
    [pan setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view]; 
}

//to make the use of gesture simultaneously within the view
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
//to make the use of gesture simultaneously
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
//to pinch the textfield using 2 fingers.
- (IBAction)scaleImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    textField1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(textField1.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
//to rotate the textfield using 2 fingers
- (IBAction)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    textField1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(textField1.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
//to remove the last textfield that was been created
-(IBAction)undo{
    UITextField *textFieldToRemove = [textfieldform lastObject];
    if (textFieldToRemove) {
        [textfieldform removeObject:textFieldToRemove];
        [textFieldToRemove removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
// for the editing of the textfield 
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{ 

    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{           

    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
    [textField1  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(248/255.0) green:(248/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
    textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldEndEditing");
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing");
    [textField1  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
}
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSLog(@"textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:");

    if ([string isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldClear:");
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn:");
    if (textField.tag == textfieldform.count) {
        textField1 = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:textfieldform.count];
        [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
//when tap the user can create a textfield on any direction, it create many different textfield. according to how many tap you do on the view
- (IBAction)handleTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:[self view]];
        textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
        [textField1 setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [textField1 setText:@"TextField"];
        CGRect frame ;    
        frame.origin.x = point.x;
        frame.origin.y = point.y; 
        frame.size.width=200;
        frame.size.height=40;
        textField1.frame=frame;
        textField1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textField1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        textField1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField1.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
        textField1.delegate = self;
        textField1.tag = textfieldform.count;
        [textfieldform addObject:textField1];
        [self.view addSubview:textField1];
        [textField1 setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong method `DoAction` as selector, instead use **`LongPressgesture`** method

Update your code like following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textfieldform = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    textField1  = ... // Initialize textfield

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *holdRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LongPressgesture:)];
    [holdRecognizer setMinimumPressDuration:2];
    [holdRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [textField1 addGestureRecognizer:holdRecognizer];
}

- (void)LongPressgesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //[textfieldform removeObject: recognizer.view];
        [recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];

        NSLog(@"Long press Ended .................");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Long press detected .....................");
    }        
}
```

Comment: it delete the whole view. and i can't create a new textfield again.

Comment: I saw that you have added long press gesture on the view. But aren't you doing like a user long presses on a `textfield` and that should be deleted?

Comment: If that's the case then add the long press gesture to the `textfield` and not your view

Comment: how can i make the long gesture to the textfield itself. because when add the gesture to the textfield programmatically, it doesn't accept the gesture.

Comment: Try like in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497152/how-to-add-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-to-a-uitextfield

Comment: I can't make it worked. can you please show me it try this. I try this to make my textfield delete with long pressed but it is not delete. http://pastebin.com/zg69z9UA.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19511/discussion-between-chinesegirl-and-user427969)

Comment: Try from the thread OR from my answer - try them separately and see which one works for you. I have updated my answer

Comment: I can move,already any textfield that i added but when im trying to make the rotate and scale but it is not functioning. http://pastie.org/5379900. here my new code.

Comment: Why are you using `textField1` in all the methods? For eg. in `(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`, you should be using `textField`

Comment: What is your other problem - actions (rotate, scale, move) on old textfield OR rotate and scale any textfield?

Comment: the action(rotate, scale and move) on old textfield. and also i am confuse why when i scale or rotate then i edit the text on the textfield, the text dissapear.

Comment: Sounds like a complicated one - post it as a new question.

Comment: actually i can rotate and scale already the old textfields, the only problem is when i edit it after i rotate and scale, the text dissapear.

Comment: Did you updated the code at `textfield1`? Also, check that when you edit a textfield (after rotating/scaling) it actually goes to `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:`

Comment: update textfield?on what way. yes when i scale & rotate when i clicked the textfield, textfielddidbeginediting & textfielddidendediting occur  since i have a nslog to check if its beginning to edit or end editing.

Comment: In `(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` and `EndEditing` methods, `textField` variable instead of `textfield1`

Comment: Yes I change textField1 to textfield already but the text is still dissapearing after i rotate and scale it.